# Typo on Winter Bash 2019 page

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, winter-bash, winter-bash-2019

Winter Bash is on!

I am very excited about hats though I don't own one yet :-(

I was just hanging around clicking on random cards on the Winter Bash [page](https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/) when I came across this after I clicked on the **"Where in the World"** card.

> Where in the World? moon and stars. ask, answer, or vote when it's December 21st anywhere in the world (this has comes in two forms, but you can only get one) You haven't earned this hat on any sites yet.

[image: Where in the World? moon and stars.]

Shouldn't it be **hat** instead of *has*?

I mean is that really a typo, or some joke I ain't getting?

Once again, a very happy "Winter Bash" and holidays to all of you here.

❄☃

Comment: If they copy pasted to create [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/339892/3) then I'd guess the other form of that has is misspelled too.

Comment: It also _bugs_ me that "ask" isn't capitalised.

Comment: @Lewis: It is the [Unix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix) influence (not a good one), and we have to live with it to this day. Unix terminals could only show lower-case characters. I was introduced to Unix in 1985 on such terminals.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like someone was conflating two sentences & came up with… ermm … neither.

> this has two forms but…

and

> this hat comes in two forms but…

Definite typo.

Same on the Day hat too

[image]

Comment: Sun and Moon... So last gen. Change that to a Sword and a Shield....